# How to access second monitor from another machine remotely which has a single monitor?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

I have 2 monitors at work (Win 7). I sometimes log into my pc remotely from a single-monitor 'demo' XP computer. In that case, the short cut keys (Windows key+ Shift+ Left/Right Arrows keys) are not working in my demo pc.

If I open any window that goes to another monitor I am unable to access it from the demo PC.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: What software are you using to remote?

Comment: i am not using any software its default with win 7 os that comes we are using.

Comment: So you are using RDP / mstsc / remote desktop is what it sounds like, that is certainly software.

Comment: yes, you are right @AthomSfere , I am using that only but I was unable to access my second monitor remotely which has a single monitor.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's more like a workaround:
In the remote connection window on your demo pc, use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to bring the window to the front, then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, choose "Move" on the popup menu, then use the arrow keys of your keyboard to move the window until you see it.

Comment: On windows 10 with remote desktop manager I had to use Alt-Del rather than alt-space to get the move menu to appear

Answer (score 6):

**Dual Monitor without remote Desktop:**

• Use ( <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> Arrow Keys) in order to move from one window to another window in Dual monitor.

**Dual Monitor with Remote Desktop:**

If you are using Remote Desktop on dual monitor, do following steps in order to move using keyboard

• First, use (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Pause</kbd>/<kbd>Break</kbd>) it will select and resize your Remote Desktop.

• Use (<kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> Arrow Keys) in order to move from one window to another window).

• Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Pause</kbd>/<kbd>Break</kbd>) it will select and full screen your remote desktop.

Answer (score 3):

You can either move your application like the above answer mentions

> (alt+tab) - to select the application
>
> (alt+space) - to open options
>
> (m) - to start moving

this will not work if the application is already fullscreen. In that case,

> use (alt+space) and (R) to restore the application
>
> and then use (alt+space) and (m) combination to start moving

Another way (not sure if this will work on < windows 10) is to use

> win+shift+ctrl+(left/right) after selecting the application

Answer (score 2):

If using 3rd party software is an option, I think TeamViewer 8 supports having multiple displays on the remote end point.

**Edit:** For the options without having any 3rd party SW, after doing some more googling, [there seems to be support already built-in in mstsc.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398865/how-do-i-enable-multiple-monitors-on-remote-desktop) using /span or /multimon switches. Depending on the version of Win7 you're running, /multimode might or might not work as "*multimon feature only works if the remote controlled computer is running Windows 7 Ultimate/Enterprise or Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard/Datacenter/Enterprise*" (quoted from the previous link).
Furthermore, since you're connecting from WinXP all this wouldn't work out of the box, but [you need to install RDP 7.0 client on the WinXP](https://superuser.com/questions/99234/remote-desktop-with-multi-monitor-support-in-xp) (which requires WinXP SP3).

Comment: I donot want to use any more softwares to be taken part to resolve this issue. Is there any thing I can resolve the issue without any third party installations? @zagrisman

Answer (score 0):

I use Citrix for the RDC. I was able to see the icon in the taskbar, but not the aplication, even using alt + tab.

To solve the problem, I had to click on the icon in the taskbar, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, and select 'Move'.